# CustomValidator message doesnt show up

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a CustomValidator and I defined every possible parameter of it:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="custom" runat="server" Text="*" ErrorMessage="This email address is already registered" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" OnServerValidate="isExist" Display="None" ValidationGroup="valRegister"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

PS: I've a RequiredFieldValidator for same textbox and I dont want to check empty value.

Here are other objects of the form:

```
<div class="row"><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Email" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail"></asp:Label><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="inpBox"></asp:TextBox></div>

<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Register" CssClass="btn" OnClick="register_member" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="valRegister" />

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="validationSummary" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="valRegister" />
```

---

```
protected void isExist(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args){
if (cre.member.isExist(args.Value)){
    args.IsValid = false;
} else {
    args.IsValid = true;
}
```

}

When I put an email already exist in the db table * appears on the form, but the error message doesnt show up. I tried all display options for custom error but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took the code exactly as in your question.

Changing `Display="None"` to `Display="Dynamic"` in the `asp:CustomValidator` causes the asterisk to appear.

Changing `ShowSummary="false"` to `ShowSummary="true"` in the `asp:ValidationSummary` causes the error message to appear in the summary.

Comment: I realized something with your answer, OnServerValidate only works if ValidationSummary > ShowSummary is "true". ShowMessageBox works on client side and because of that OnServerValidate doesnt work.

I solved my problem by adding an ajax call to an aspx page to check entered email address and then I used ClientValidationFunction to call that js function.

Comment: Aha! Sorry, I didn't realize it was the messagebox validation error you were after. Yes, if you want the client-side messagebox but require the server's involvement (e.g. to check for an email address in a database) then you will have to do something like this.

Comment: It works fine in normal case, but as soon I put the form controls inside an update panel, all validators get their error messages displayed fine (within the validation summary) **EXCEPT** the custom validator one. Still don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `Display` to `"Dynamic"` or anything doesn't really do anything if the server is not handling the validation **manually**, especially when using `<asp:CustomValidator`. Even a `ValidationGroup` with or without a `ValidationSummary` does nothing.

Always force a validation on the server **before** allowing the user to exit the form/gridview/etc.

ie

```
            ...your form here...
             <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center" valign="top">
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" CausesValidation="true"  />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="Cancel_Click" CausesValidation="false"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>

...
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
           //processing done after a successful submit here!
        }
    }
```

The `Page.Validate()` will force the validation controls to check and display your error message.